# Python: deselect outliner elements

Tags: python, outliner

How can I deselect **Text** in the outliner? `bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')` will not work for this. I can just click with the mouse on **Plane** in the outliner and it works, but I want to do this in Python and didn't find a way yet.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That highlight is indicating the current active object.
I was about to tell you that you can't really do that, since most of that data is read-only, but after some stubborn, extra googling, it turns out you actually can!

```
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = None
```

I guess we both learned something new today.